# Establish a constant (S)FTP connection with PHP Daemon script

Tags: php, ftp, connection, sftp

Is there a way to establish a constant connection to a FTP or SFTP server using the built-in PHP functions in a PHP file, which is being run as a Daemon process? At present I use something like:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('ip', port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$dir = 'ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/./';
```

But I have to open new connection every time I have to perform an action such as creating, editing or deleting a file or listing a directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to open new connection for every action.

The `$sftp` is a resource that represents the connection. Just keep it and reuse it for every action.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('ip', port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream1 = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');

// later...

$stream2 = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');
```

Comment: I am in the process of building an ajax web application having the functionality of an ftp client. Every time the user click on a directory, file, etc, an ajax request is sent to the respective controller/action and it opens a new ftp connection. That's why I want to keep the connection alive using a daemon or any other technology.

Comment: So the deamon will keep the connection as described in my answer. And you need to develop a mechanism to allow your controller to communicate with the deamon.

Comment: Any tutorials/suggestions on how to build this mechanism?

Comment: @ГеоргиБанков That's for a separate question.